# How to prove this statement re continuous functions and convergence

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I read that given a mapping $f$ from a metric space $(X,d_x)$ to a metric space $(Y,d_y)$, if $f$ is continuous, for any sequence $\{x_1,x_2,..\}$ in $X$ that converges to a point $\bar{x}$, the corresponding sequence in the image, i.e. $\{f(x_1),f(x_2),...\}$ in $Y$ converges to $f(\bar{x})$.

If $f$ is uniformly continuous, the statement can be proven, but I could not figure out how to prove the statement if 'uniform' is left out...

Comment: Isn't that the definition of continuity ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yes I was suspecting that .. but from my readings $f$ is continuous if the inverse image of every open set in $Y$ is also open ... am not sure how to relate this definition with the above statement which uses converging sequences ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function, and $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ a sequence of elements of $X$ converging to an $x \in X$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Because $f$ is continuous, the preimage of the open ball $B(f(x),\varepsilon)$ by $f$ is open in $X$ : in particular, because $x$ belongs to this preimage, there exists $\alpha >0$ such that $B(x, \alpha) \subset f^{-1}(B(f(x), \varepsilon))$.

Now, because $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ converges to $x$, there exists an integer $N \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $x_n \in B(x, \alpha)$. In particular, for all $n \geq N$, $f(x_n) \in f(B(x,\alpha)) \subset B(f(x), \varepsilon)$.

So we proved here that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $f(x_n) \in B(f(x), \varepsilon)$ : this is exactly the definition of the convergence of the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ to $f(x)$.